# Prevent UglifyJS from changing function arguments' names

Tags: javascript, meteor, uglifyjs

When deploying my app on a test server, I came with an error where UglifyJS did change a npm dependency module's functions arguments, where the names of these arguments are important; some functions are called dynamically and I am using [function-arguments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-arguments) to map certain values to certain function arguments based on their corresponding names.

Is it possible to tell UglifyJS to skip certain modules, or files, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) you can use `mangle` options to for that:

- `mangle` (default `true`) — pass `false` to skip mangling names, or pass an object to specify mangling options

Object options:

- `except` - pass an `Array` of identifiers that should be excluded from mangling
- `toplevel` — mangle names declared in the toplevel scope (disabled by default).
- `eval` — mangle names visible in scopes where eval or with are used (disabled by default).
- `keep_fnames` -- default `false`. Pass `true` to not mangle function names. Useful for code relying on Function.prototype.name.

---

```
//tst.js
var globalVar;
function funcName(firstLongName, anotherLongName)
{
  var myVariable = firstLongName +  anotherLongName;
}

UglifyJS.minify("tst.js").code;
// 'function funcName(a,n){}var globalVar;'

UglifyJS.minify("tst.js", { mangle: { except: ['firstLongName'] } }).code;
// 'function funcName(firstLongName,a){}var globalVar;'

UglifyJS.minify("tst.js", { mangle: { toplevel: true } }).code;
// 'function n(n,a){}var a;'
```

I tried to find an option to mangle the function names and skip mangling the arguments and didn't fun that so far (not saying there isn't...)